# Plotly? How to change the whisker length and color individual boxplots simultaneously in plotly Python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Here is the code from the webpage:
https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/

I want to be able to change the color of every individual boxplot while keeping control of quartiles and fences:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=[
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
        [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
      ], name="Precompiled Quartiles"))

fig.update_traces(q1=[ 1, 2, 3 ], median=[ 4, 5, 6 ],
                  q3=[ 7, 8, 9 ], lowerfence=[-1, 0, 1],
                  upperfence=[5, 6, 7], mean=[ 2.2, 2.8, 3.2 ],
                  sd=[ 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 ], notchspan=[ 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 ] )

fig.show()
```

Comment: Pls clarify on "keeping control of quartiles and fences". What are you expecting?

Comment: I just want two things: 
-Vary q1,q3,median,lowerfence and upper fence. 
 -Change color of individual box (For this example - red, green and blue)
Basically, in the same code given on the website, how do I change the colors.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colors and the values for q1, q3, etc., you can use the below updated code. Change the values in the `myq1`, `myq3` and other array to change the values. The colors can be changed using the `marker_color`. The underlying data points, however are not visible. Hope this helps.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#fig = go.Figure()
myq1=[ 2, 3, 4 ]
myq3=[ 8, 9, 10 ]
mymedian=[ 4, 5, 6 ]
mymean=[ 2.2, 2.8, 3.2 ]
mylowerfence=[ 0, 1, 2 ]
mynotchspan=[ 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 ]
mysd=[ 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 ]
mylowerfence=[ 0, 1, 2 ]
myupperfence=[9, 10, 11]


trace0 = go.Box( y=[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], name="Quartile1", marker_color='#3D9970', q1=[myq1[0]], 
                median=[mymedian[0]], q3 = [myq3[0]], lowerfence=[mylowerfence[0]], upperfence=[myupperfence[0]], 
                mean=[mymean[0]],sd=[mysd[0]], notchspan=[mynotchspan[0]])

trace1 = go.Box( y=[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], name="Quartile2", marker_color='#FF4136', q1=[myq1[1]], 
                median=[mymedian[1]], q3 = [myq3[1]], lowerfence=[mylowerfence[1]], upperfence=[myupperfence[1]], 
                mean=[mymean[1]],sd=[mysd[1]], notchspan=[mynotchspan[1]])

trace2 = go.Box( y=[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], name="Quartile3", marker_color='#FF851B', q1=[myq1[2]], 
                median=[mymedian[2]], q3 = [myq3[2]], lowerfence=[mylowerfence[2]],upperfence=[myupperfence[2]], 
                mean=[mymean[2]],sd=[mysd[2]], notchspan=[mynotchspan[2]])

fig=go.Figure(data=[trace0, trace1, trace2])

fig.update_traces(orientation='v')
fig.update_layout(boxmode='group')                  
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Tt works great for no outliers. But when I specify boxpoints = 'outliers', it doesn't show outliers.

Comment: Hi @Patrck - you wont be able to see the outliers when there are separate traces, which is required for different colors.